# Balanced Binary Search Trees on the basis of size of left and right child subtrees

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between nearly balanced BST and nearly Complete Binary tree. Even if the definition of the former is clear then we can differenciate, but not able to get a relevant article.
2. Today, in my class I was taught about the condition to be balanced as:

   > *max( size(root.left) , size(root.right) ) <= 3*n/4* ------------ (eqn 1).
   >   Hence, H(n) = height for the tree of n nodes following the above property < = 1+H(3*n/4).
   >   Continuing the recursive steps we get the bound for logn.

   My question is that, is this a specific type of BST ? For example in case of AVL trees, as I remember the condtion is that the difference in the heights of left and right childs being atmost 1, or is this a more general result and the equation 1 as stated earlier can be reduced to prove the result for AVL Trees as well ? i.e. any Balanced BST will result in difference of heights of siblings being atmost 1 ?
   In case its different than AVL, how do we manage the Insertion and Delete Operations in this new kind of tree ?

EDIT : Also if you can explain why 3*n/4 only ?
My Thought: It is because we can then surely say that H(n) <= 1+H(3*n/4), since if we take something like 3n/5 less than 3n/4 then H(3n/5) wont be necessarily less that H(2n/5) as the raio of 3n/5 and 2n/5 is less than 2 and as we know a factor of 2 for number of nodes increases the height by 1.
So we wont surely write H(n) <= 1 + H(3n/5), it may be H(2n/5) in place of H(3n/5) as well, am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A nearly **complete** BST is a BST where all levels are filled, except the last one. Definitions are kind of messed up here (some call this property *perfect*). Please refer to  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#cite_note-almost_complete_binary_tree-20) for this.
   Being **balanced** is a less strict criterion, i.e. all (nearly) complete BSTs are balanced, but not all balanced BSTs are complete. In that Wikipedia article is a definition for that too. Im my world a BST is balanced, if it leads to O(log n) operation cost.
2. For example, one can say, a BST is balanced, if each subtree has at most  epsilon * n nodes, where epsilon < 1 (for example epsilon = 3/4 or even epsilon = 0.999 -- which are *practically* not balanced at all).
   The reason for that is that the height of such a BST is roughly log_{1/epsilon} n = log_2 n / (- log_2 epsilon) = O(log n), but 1 / (- log_2 0.99) = 99.5 is a huge constant. You can try to prove that with the usual ration of epsilon = 1/2, where both subtrees have roughly the same size.

I don't know of a common BST, which uses this 3/4. Common BSTs are for example [Red-Black-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), [Splay-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) or - if you are on  a hard disk - a whole family of [B-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). For your example, you can probably implement the operations by augumenting each node with two integers representing the number of nodes in the left and the right subtree respectively. When inserting or deleting  someting, you update the numbers as you walk from the root to the leaf (or up) and if the condition is validated, you do a rotation.

Comment: 1. Nearly balanced any special definition ?

Comment: I don't know of any. Either O(log n) operation complexity meaning balanced, or O(n) worst case which means unbalanced.